# Retrieving the highest and lowest closing price of n weeks before in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, price

I am coding an indicator which can be applied to a daily candles chart and do the following:

1. Retrieve the highest and lowest of the current week and of the n weeks before (n given in input), and put in an array
2. Retrieve the highest and lowest closing price of the current week and of the n weeks before (n given in input), and put in an array
3. For each week calculate the difference between High and Low and make a simple average
4. For each week calculate the difference between Highest Closing Price and Lowest Closing Price and make a simple average

The difficulty is to write the right instruction to retrieve values since I cannot count candles but I have to tell the program to considers the weeks.

The code below gives an error on the line below saying that float is not a valid keyword

```
float highLowDiff(week) =>
```

```
//@version=5
indicator("Weekly Averages", overlay=true)

// Input for the number of weeks to consider
var int numWeeks = input(4, title="Number of Weeks", minval=1)

// Arrays to store weekly data
var float[] weeklyHighs = array.new_float(0)
var float[] weeklyLows = array.new_float(0)
var float[] weeklyCloseHighs = array.new_float(0)
var float[] weeklyCloseLows = array.new_float(0)
var float[] weeklyHighLowDiffAvg = array.new_float(0)
var float[] weeklyCloseDiffAvg = array.new_float(0)

// Function to calculate the difference between High and Low
float highLowDiff(week) =>
    highVal = ta.highest(high, week)
    lowVal = ta.lowest(low, week)
    highVal - lowVal

// Function to calculate the difference between Highest Closing Price and Lowest Closing Price
float closeDiff(week) =>
    closeVal = ta.highest(close, week)
    closeLowVal = ta.lowest(close, week)
    closeVal - closeLowVal

// Calculate and store weekly data
for i = 0 to numWeeks do
    week = ta.bar_index[1] - ta.bar_index[1][1]
    array.push(weeklyHighs, highLowDiff(week))
    array.push(weeklyLows, lowVal)
    array.push(weeklyCloseHighs, closeDiff(week))
    array.push(weeklyCloseLows, closeLowVal)

// Calculate simple averages for High-Low differences and Close differences
for i = 0 to numWeeks do
    avgHighLowDiff = ta.sma(weeklyHighs[i], numWeeks)
    avgCloseDiff = ta.sma(weeklyCloseHighs[i], numWeeks)
    array.push(weeklyHighLowDiffAvg, avgHighLowDiff)
    array.push(weeklyCloseDiffAvg, avgCloseDiff)

// Plot the averages
plot(weeklyHighLowDiffAvg, title="High-Low Difference Average", color=color.blue)
plot(weeklyCloseDiffAvg, title="Close Difference Average", color=color.red)
```